# Azure B2C Skip Self-Asserted Social Signup. Show error if federated user doesn't already exist

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am pre-creating federated users using the Graph API. Although I am using a SignUpSignIn custom policy, I want to be able to prevent a SignUp and show an error when a federated user is not already in the B2C directory. I have tried just removing the orchestration step that does SelfAsserted-Social but that didn't yield intended results.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this doing the following

1. Create a claim type to hold the message to the user
2. Create a claims transformation of type CreateStringClaim that populates the above claim type
3. Created a self-asserted technical profile that
   a. hides the continue and cancel buttons
   b. has an InputClaimsTransformation referencing 2. above.
   c. has an Input claim of the claim type in 1. above
   d. has an output claim of the claim type in 1. above
4. Remove/comment out the orchestration step that shows the self-asserted page for auth with social Idp
5. In the orchestration step that writes the federated account to AAD, I replace the referenced TP (AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId) with the one in 3.

Later I will be using a ContentDefinition element to have the page that displays the error message contain a link that sends the user back to the beginning signin user journey.

Comment: Glad to know this issue is resolved. you can mark your own answer as accepted so that this post can be found easily.

Comment: In order to avoid misleading others, I delete my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Allen! Will be able to in a few hours.

Answer (score -1):

I'm experiencing the same problem you had here, but unfortunately I'm not yet able to get what you did in those 5 steps.
I know 2 years have passed, but if still have access to the files which you used to do this that would be great!